# Window functions assume null sorts low - expected behavior?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

The following will not properly count nulls within a window...

```
select *,
    sum(case when value is null then 1 else 0 end)
        over(partition by id
            order by coalesce(value,9999999)) as NumNulls,
    row_number()
        over(partition by id
            order by coalesce(value,9999999)) as RN
from temp
```

Obviously, the problem can be solved using `rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following`, so it's not a big deal. But, given my understanding of SQL, I would not have expected this result. Have I missed a finer point of the language, or is this unexpected behavior?

Here's a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98285/3

Comment: Yes, NULLs sort first, if that is the gist of your question. `SELECT x = 1 UNION ALL SELECT NULL ORDER BY x;` Without knowing what results you expect from this specific query, and how they differ from the results you're getting, not sure how else to comment...

Comment: I think you are confusing `OVER` and `GROUP BY` here

Comment: I would expect the `numnulls` column in the result to contain the value of 1 on each row having an ID of 1, since there is 1 null value associated with ID 1. However, you actually get a mixed bag - 0, 0, 1. It's like SQL Server just assumed that null would always be sorted low and doesn't bother checking the rest of the column, even when you're sorting differently...

Comment: "Where it is not explicitly specified, the default window frame is “range between unbounded preceding and current row”, in other words, the top row in the window is the first row in the current partition, and the bottom row in the window is the current row." I stand corrected. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

To reach your expected results you need to this

```
 SELECT *
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value ) AS NumNulls
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY value) AS RN
FROM #temp
```

because you used `coalesce` it could not partition properly this your count was off.